# Previous shutdown cause: -59

Tags: shutdown

My MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2019) keeps on shutting down overnight. When I come to it in the morning and try to turn it on, it takes at least 10 seconds of holding the power button to turn it on. If I check the kernel logs, among the normal codes, like 5 and sometimes 3, I see this:
`kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -59`

I've done some looking, and can't find the code -59 anywhere.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Negative numbers are typically hardware.  5 is normal shutdown and 3 is power button held. Start with [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (hold `D` while booting)  See if you get any results

Comment: @Allan I just tried it, it came up with nothing. It only shuts down overnight, never when I am using it, and if it's on power, it won't do it

Comment: Is it sleeping (or supposed to be sleeping) when it shuts down?

Comment: Yes it is, I shut the laptop overnight, and when I come to it in the morning, it's shut down. If it's charging, it won't shut down.